# json.parse is given an undefined:1

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning express.js and I have the assignment to make a web app exchange the cryptocurrency into Fiat currency so far everything  is good but when I use json.parsa on the data I got from the HTTP request I give me an error here is the Jason data I get from the HTTP request

```
{
"ask": 9179.74,
"bid": 9174.32,
"last": 9176.57,
"high": 9223.61,
"low": 8781.94,
"volume": 50371.1269628,
"open": {
"hour": 9177.42,
"day": 8855.65,
"week": 9765.14,
"month": 7720.07,
"month_3": 8808.98,
"month_6": 7266.43,
"year": 8770.7
},
"averages": {
"day": 8943.05,
"week": 9089.32,
"month": 9105.24
},
"changes": {
"price": {
"hour": -0.85,
"day": 320.92,
"week": -588.57,
"month": 1456.5,
"month_3": 367.58,
"month_6": 1910.14,
"year": 405.87
},
"percent": {
"hour": -0.01,
"day": 3.62,
"week": -6.03,
"month": 18.87,
"month_3": 4.17,
"month_6": 26.29,
"year": 4.63
}
},
"volume_percent": 64.54,
"timestamp": 1590598912,
"display_timestamp": "2020-05-27 17:01:52",
"display_symbol": "BTC-USD"
}
```

and this is my code

```
     app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    request('https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD',{

        'auth':{
           'user': 'sohailahmadpsh@gmail.com',
           'pass': 'YjY0MGEwYjg2MTJkNGQ3ZDkyY2JlMzZmNDllNTgxZjA'
        }
    },function (error, response, result) { 
        var data=JSON.parse(result);
        var price=data.last;  
        res.send(price);
    });


});
```

and the things I have already tried 
is used `console.log(typeof result)` and I give me a string even know that is a string 
and the error I am getting is

```
 undefined:1
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Request._callback (D:\backend\Bitcoins-app\server.js:25:23)
```

Comment: If that's what you get, you already have JSON and don't need to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your json is already parsed. Try commenting out the line parsing the response.

Comment: hi, sir, I check the code and accidentally add wrong code I have edited the code plz take a look at it and I already have tried that when I comment the parsed line the response gives me only undefined the rest of the error goes away when i use this two lines of code instead of that those  var price=result.last; res.send(price);

Comment: Could you try doing console.log(response) and see what you get in your console. Alternatively, try swapping result out for response.

Comment: yes, sir, I get a lot of data about the request I send like is status code and a lot of other stuff by the way the status code is 200

Comment: Great. Then try console.log(response.data) this should contain the data that was returned to you. So response.data.last should contain the value you are looking for.

Comment: hi sir, when I put the response directly in the console.log(response), then status code is 403 but if I put the 'response' in a variable before console.log() like this var status = response;  console.log(status) then I get a status code of 200 is this suppose to happen

Comment: Okay.. odd.. what is the contents of console.log(data) then?

Comment: hi, sir, I tried console.log(response.data) I get an error say TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined but if I but the response.data in a variable and then console.log it then I only get undefined

Comment: console.log(data) give me this error ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand completely. Did you try swapping: var data = JSON.parse(result) for var data = response.data?

Comment: when i swap the var data = JSON.parse(result) for var data = response.data and i get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'last' of undefined

Comment: Try console.log(result) and see what you get. Depending on the contents you may be able to figure out if it is already parsed and if it even contains the latest price.

Comment: hi sir the data I am receiving from an HTTP request is not already parse because when I console.log(typeof result) it give a string so it not already parse and in my question, the first code is the data I am receiving from an HTTP request

Comment: The unexpected token U error is usually because you are trying to parse something that is in fact, undefined. Can you add a screenshot of console.log(result) and console.log(response). I have to see what is going on, to help further.

Comment: hi, sir, I solved that problem actually it was a problem with API authentication thanks